# Run command on complex schedule in python

Tags: python, job-scheduling

I know there are a lot of schedule  and event libraries out there but I haven’t found one where I can make complex schedule. E.g

- run python command every 500ms between 7.55 and 8.05 on Monday-Friday

Anyone who can easily crack that task in Python? I have considered using `schedule` but as far as I can tell then I can’t add something like every 500 ms. Although I do believe in a cron-like approach (except cron only allows down to every minute).

I’m thinking of calculating next “cron” time and then use `sched` to execute the command with the calculated delay. No idea how to calculate something like that though. I could someone already cracked this challenge though.

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example and https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. In this example, we need to see your current code, what attempts you have tried, and way more information (run jobs at 500ms intervals? What is 7.55 and 8.05 on weekdays? Define weekday?), your current results, and an example of your desired results. Until then, I am flagging this post for removal.

Comment: There is no current code because I have no idea how to implement this. I was considering something like cron but cron wouldn’t work. Weekday is mon-fri

Comment: What is a job? Is that one part of a single `.py` file, an entire `.py` file, multiple `.py` files? What is `7.55`? What is `8.05`?  How is that a `complex schedule`? Why can't you just use Windows Event Scheduler? A Linux bash script? This question is not within the scope of Stack Overflow since we are not a code writing service.

Comment: I meant python command - not a job. You seriously don’t know when somebody talks  about the time between 07.55 - 08.05? A 10 minute span - not sure how to clarify that. And no it isn’t that complex but too complex for existing python libraries it seems. I disagree with you, I am asking for input/help - not for a code writing service ! And I’m asking for a python solution here!

Comment: Any post without code is going to have a hard time getting an answer, since the goal is typically to help with problems in _existing_ code (in fact, your question will probably end up marked as "off-topic" based on the question). That being said, you're most likely going to have to do a roll-your-own scheduler since you need ms precision - I suggest starting with the `datetime` and `threading` modules (specifically the `Timer` class), which is what similar questions have done.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the [`apscheduler`](https://apscheduler.readthedocs.io/en/stable/modules/triggers/combining.html#module-apscheduler.triggers.combining) supports exactly what I'm looking for.